# Numpy FileNotFoundError on python script for data preparation

Tags: python, numpy, path

I am currently struggeling to accomplish step 1.1 ("Prepare your data") on this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/RussellSB/tt-vae-gan).
The point of the according script is to organize audiofiles (MIT Flickr 8k Audio Corpus) in a specific way which is needed for further procedure.

**The copied script looks like this:**

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import argparse
import shutil
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--dataroot", type=str, default='/Users/luca/Desktop/flickr_audio', help="data root of flickr")
parser.add_argument("--outdir", type=str, default='/Users/luca/Desktop/dataprepped', help="output directory")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

# This just gets the filenames with speaker referenes (because it is not clear in the filename otherwise)
textin = args.dataroot + 'wav2spk.txt'
speaker_files = np.genfromtxt(textin, dtype=[('mystring','S27'),('myint','i8')], delimiter=' ')

# Saves wavs belonging to speaker from list of speaker files
def flickr_prep_wavs(outdir, speaker_files, src):
    os.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)
    
    files = [filename for (filename, spk) in speaker_files if spk == src]
    for filename in tqdm(files, desc="extracting spk %s"%src):
        f = args.dataroot + 'wavs/' + filename.decode()   
        shutil.copy(f, outdir)

# Data preparation
flickr_prep_wavs(args.outdir+'spkr_1', speaker_files, 4)
flickr_prep_wavs(args.outdir+'spkr_2', speaker_files, 7)
#flickr_prep_wavs(args.outdir+'spkr_3', speaker_files, 49)  # uncomment to include another female
#flickr_prep_wavs(args.outdir+'spkr_4', speaker_files, 17)  # uncomment to include another male
```

The only thing I adjusted were the folder-paths in the parser arguments.

**The Error message is the following:**

```
Namespace(dataroot='/Users/luca/Desktop/flickr_audio', outdir='/Users/luca/Desktop/dataprepped')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/luca/PycharmProjects/datascript/flickr.py", line 15, in <module>
    speaker_files = np.genfromtxt(textin, dtype=[('mystring','S27'),('myint','i8')], delimiter=' ')

  File "/Users/luca/PycharmProjects/datascript/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1813, in genfromtxt
    fid = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)

  File "/Users/luca/PycharmProjects/datascript/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 193, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)

  File "/Users/luca/PycharmProjects/datascript/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 532, in open
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"{path} not found.")

FileNotFoundError: /Users/luca/Desktop/flickr_audiowav2spk.txt not found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think it has something to do with maybe a parsing of a wrong path(?!) as I am new to MacOS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can only guess. Is the txt-file located in the right directory? And is it `/Users/luca/Desktop/flickr_audio/wav2spk.txt` instead of `/Users/luca/Desktop/flickr_audiowav2spk.txt` (missing `/`)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It was indeed a problem with the path.
It should've been named "/Users/luca/Desktop/flickr_audio/" with a slash at the end. It worked fine now.